# Cannot replace with Java replace method

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that censors the word "dang" with a "#!". My main method passes in a String sentence.

```
public static String deleteDang(String sentence)
    /* pre: receives the sentence to be censored
       post: returns the censored sentence*/
    {
        while(((sentence.toLowerCase()).contains("dang")))
        {
            sentence = (sentence.toLowerCase()).replace("dang", "#!");
        }
        return sentence;
    }
```

I want it to be work so that I can enter something such as "DANG ApplE" and get the output "!# ApplE". When I attempt to run this, it outputs "!# apple" if I input "dang apple", but when I put in "DANG Apple", I have an infinite output of "DANG Apple". What am I doing wrong?

If possible, I would like to this without the use of .replaceAll

Comment: I don't see you outputting anything. Where does this happen?

Comment: Also, why would you expect `"dang"` to replace anything in `"DANG Apple"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a case insensitive regular expression, for example...

```
String sentance = "Dang the dang and DANG and I don't mind a dANg";
sentance = sentance.replaceAll("(?i)dang", "#!");
System.out.println(sentance);
```

Which will output something like...

```
#! the #! and #! and I don't mind a #!
```

**Updated based on comments**

Without the ability to use `replaceAll`, you will have to split the `String` into sections, one way is to loop over the `String`, trimming off the "dang"s and building a new `String` from it, for example...

```
String sentance = "Dang the dang and DANG and I don't mind a dANg and some more";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentance.length());
while (sentance.toLowerCase().contains("dang")) {

    int index = sentance.toLowerCase().indexOf("dang");
    String start = sentance.substring(0, index);
    int endIndex = index + "dang".length();
    sb.append(start);
    sb.append("#!");

    sentance = sentance.substring(endIndex);

}

sb.append(sentance);

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**Updated**

You could use the case insensitive regular expression and `String#split` which will break the `String` into an array around the expression, you would then be able to rebuild the `String` from these parts...

```
String sentance = "Bang Dang the dang and DANG and I don't mind a dANg and some more";
String[] split = sentance.split("(?i)dang");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentance.length());
for (int index = 0; index < split.length - 1; index++) {
    String part = split[index];
    System.out.println("[" + part + "] " + part.trim().isEmpty());
    if (!part.trim().isEmpty()) {
        sb.append(part).append("#!");
    } else {
        sb.append("#!");
    }
}
// Put the last value at the end, so we don't end up with #! at the end of the String
sb.append(split[split.length - 1]);

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I've not done any range checking (checking to see if there are enough parts returned), so you will need to do you own testing, but the ideas there...

Comment: Is there a way that I could do it by iterating? I am trying to understand this for a class and my teacher doesn't want us to use .replaceAll yet.

Comment: Thanks a ton!The first update is really helpful and now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate. You can just use `replaceAll` method

```
sentence = sentence.replaceAll("dang", "#!");
```

This will only consider the exact word "dang"

If you want to replace all dang word without considering the case
then you can try

```
 sentence = sentence.replaceAll("(?!)dang", "#!");
```